# Remove substrings between < and > (including the brackets) with no angle brackets inside

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have to modify a html-like text with the sed command. I have to delete substrings starting with one or more `<` chars, then having 0 or more occurrences of any characters but angle brackets and then any 1 or more `>` chars.

For example: from
`aaa<bbb>ccc` I would like to get `aaaccc`

I am able to do this with

`"s/<[^>]\+>//g"`

but this command doesn't work if between `<>` characters is an empty string, or if there is double `<<>>` in the text.
For example, from

```
aa<>bb<cc>vv<<gg>>h
```

I get

```
aa<>bbvv>h
```

instead of

```
aabbvvh
```

How can I modify it to give me the right result?

Comment: This is tricky, what if the text were `a<"echo x >> y">b`?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1486848

Comment: When you speak about HTML-like language, could you state that your input file meets the requirements to be an well formed XML file? If it is the case, the solution is trivial with XML tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/<\+[^>]*>\+//g'
sed 's/<\{1,\}[^>]*>\{1,\}//g'
sed -E 's/<+[^>]*>+//g'
```

The patterns match

- `<\+` / `<\{1,\}` - 1 or more occurrences of `<` char
- `[^>]*` - negated bracket expression that matches 0 or more chars other than `>`
- `>\+` / `>\{1,\}` - 1 or more occurrences of `>` char

Note that in the last, POSIX ERE, example, `+` that is unescaped is a quantifier matching 1 or more occurrences, same as `\+` in the POSIX BRE pattern.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/odRIz9):

```
s='aa<>bb<cc>vv<<gg>>h'
sed 's/<\+[^>]*>\+//g' <<< "$s"
sed 's/<\{1,\}[^>]*>\{1,\}//g' <<< "$s"
sed -E 's/<+[^>]*>+//g' <<< "$s"
```

Result of each sed command is `aabbvvh`.

Comment: This will still give the wrong output on many input strings. @potong gave an example in a Comment under the original question. Another example - the third solution on the input string `<a<b>c>` will return `c>`. I don't think this kind of problem has a one-line solution in the most general case, even assuming that "the most general case" can be defined correctly.

Comment: @mathguy The OP said: *I have to delete all strings between <>, including the <>.* and the example is `aa<>bb<cc>vv<<gg>>h`. I understand OP wants to match any substring from a `<` until the next closest `>`, with any amount of `<` and `>` at the start/end. Since the answer is accepted, it was exactly what OP expects. The cases you and potong might have in mind are most likely are not in scope of the question. I will edit it so that future readers had a clear vision of what kind of strings the question is about.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that once you allow nesting the `<` and `>` characters, you convert the language type from *"regular"* to *"context free"*.

Regular languages are those that are matched by regular expressions, while context free grammars cannot be parsed in general by a regular expression.  The *unbounded* level of nesting is what impedes this, needing a pile based automaton to be able to parse such languages.

But there's a little complicated workaround to this, if you consider that there's an upper limit to the level of nesting you will allow in the text you are facing, then you can convert into regular a language that is not, based on the premise that *the non-regular cases will never occur:*

Let's suppose you will never have more than three levels of nesting into your pattern, (this allows you to see the pattern and be able to extend it to N levels) you can use the following algorithm to build a regular expression that will allow you to match three levels of nesting, but no more (you can make a regexp to parse N levels, but no more, this is the *umbounded* *bounded* nature of regexps :) ).

Let's construct the expression recursively from the bottom up.  With only one level of nesting, you have only `<` and `>` and you cannot find neither of these inside (if you allow `<` you allow more nesting levels, which is forbidden at level 0):

```
{l0} = [^<>]*
```

a string including no `<` and `>` characters.

Your matching text will be of this class of strings, surrounded by a pair of `<` and `>` chars:

```
{l1} = <[^<>]*>
```

Now, you can build a second level of nesting by alternating `{l0}{l1}{l0}{l1}...{l0}` (this is, `{l0}({l1}{l0})*` and surrounding the whole thing with `<` and `>`, to build `{l2}`

```
{l2} = <{l0}({l1}{l0})*> = <[^<>]*(<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>
```

Now, you can build a third, by alternating sequences of `{l0}` and `{l2}` in a pair of brackets... (remember that `{l-i}` represents a regexp that allows upto `i` levels of nesting or less)

```
{l3} = <{l0}({l2}{l0})*> = <[^<>]*(<[^<>]*(<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>[^<>]*)*>
```

and so on, successively, you form a sequence of

```
{lN} = <{l0}({l(N-1)}{l0})*>
```

and stop when you consider there will not be a deeper nesting in your input file.

So your level three regexp is:

```
<[^<>]*(<[^<>]*(<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>[^<>]*)*>
{l3--------------------------------------}
<{l0--}({l2---------------------}{l0--})*>
        <{l0--}({l1----}{l0--})*>
                <{l0--}>
```

You can see that the regexp grows as you consider more levels.  The good things is that you can consider a maximum level of three or four and most text will fit in this cathegory.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mnJM92/1/).

## NOTE

Never hesitate to build a regular expression, despite of it appearing somewhat complex.  Think that you can *build* it inside your program, just using the techniques I've used to build it (e.g. for a 16 level nesting regexp, you'll get a large string, very difficult to write it by hand, but very easy to build with a computer)

```
package com.stackoverflow.q61630608;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NestingRegex {

    public static String build_regexp( char left, char right, int level ) {
        return level == 0
                ? "[^" + left + right + "]*"
                : level == 1
                        ? left + build_regexp( left, right, 0 ) + right
                        : left + build_regexp( left, right, 0 )
                        + "(" + build_regexp( left, right, level - 1 )
                        + build_regexp( left, right, 0 )
                        + ")*" + right;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
            System.out.println( "{l" + i + "} = "
                    + build_regexp( '<', '>', i ) );
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( build_regexp( '<', '>', 16 ), 0 );
        String s = "aa<>bb<cc>vv<<gg>>h<iii<jjj>kkk<<lll>mmm>ooo>ppp";
        System.out.println(
                String.format( "pat.matcher(\"%s\").replaceAll(\"@\") => %s",
                               s, pat.matcher( s ).replaceAll( "@" ) ) );
    }


}
```

which, on run gives:

```
{l0} = [^<>]*
{l1} = <[^<>]*>
{l2} = <[^<>]*(<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>
{l3} = <[^<>]*(<[^<>]*(<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>[^<>]*)*>
{l4} = <[^<>]*(<[^<>]*(<[^<>]*(<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>[^<>]*)*>[^<>]*)*>
pat.matcher("aa<>bb<cc>vv<<gg>>h<iii<jjj>kkk<<lll>mmm>ooo>ppp").replaceAll("@") => aa@bb@vv@h@ppp
```

The main advantage of using regular expressions is that once you have written it, it compiles into an internal representation that only has to visit each character of the string being matched once, leading to a very efficient final matching code (probably you'll not get so efficient writing the code yourself)

## Sed

for sed, you only need to generate an enough deep regexp, and use it to parse your text file:

```
sed 's/<[^<>]*\(<[^<>]*\(<[^<>]*\(<[^<>]*\(<[^<>]*\(<[^<>]*>[^<>]*\)*>[^<>]*\)*>[^<>]*\)*>[^<>]*\)*>[^<>]*\)*>//g' file1.xml
```

will give you appropiate results (this is 6 levels of nesting or less ---remember the `(` and `)` must be escaped to be considered group delimiters in `sed`)

Your regexp can be constructed using shell variables with the following approach:

```
l0="[^<>]*"
l1="<${l0}>"
l2="<${l0}\(${l1}${l0}\)*>"
l3="<${l0}\(${l2}${l0}\)*>"
l4="<${l0}\(${l3}${l0}\)*>"
l5="<${l0}\(${l4}${l0}\)*>"
l6="<${l0}\(${l5}${l0}\)*>"
echo regexp is "${l6}"
regexp is <[^<>]*\(<[^<>]*\(<[^<>]*\(<[^<>]*\(<[^<>]*\(<[^<>]*>[^<>]*\)*>[^<>]*\)*>[^<>]*\)*>[^<>]*\)*>[^<>]*\)*>
sed -e "s/${l6}/@/g" <<EOF
aa<>bb<cc>vv<<gg>>h<iii<jj<>j>k<k>k<<lll>mmm>ooo>ppp
EOF
aa@bb@vv@h@ppp
```

(I've used `@` as substitution pattern, instead, so you can see where in the input string have the patterns been detected)